# Magento2 : CRUD Module Add Button Not Showing

Tags: magento2, module, crud

Starting with this sample, https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-sample-module, I'm trying to make a CRUD manager module.

I went through the sample and changed everything I could find that looked like it needed changing and now the Add button isn't showing:

[image: CRUD Module Header]
There should be an orange button that says "Add New Vehicle"

Heres the file where I define the label:

```
/Block/Adminhtml/Post.php

<?php

namespace Ekko\FitmentManager\Block\Adminhtml;

class Post extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Container
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_post';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'Ekko_FitmentManager';
        $this->_headerText = __('Vehicles');
        $this->_addButtonLabel = __('Add New Vehicle');
        parent::_construct();
    }
}
```

Not sure what other files have to do with the button, but I'm pretty sure its not this one thats causing the problem.

For reference, this is what it should look like:
[image]

Comment: https://www.maximehuran.fr/en/magento-2-training-2/ help for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below module creator for such CRUD operation. It will generate similar module with grid as well as add new button, edit and delete.

Module Creator URL: http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/magento2x.php

Comment: Not exactly an answer to my question, but it helped cut out a lot of work, so I'll give you the credit. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome. Glad to hear that it helped you.